# Extract N lines with no duplicate strings from either of the two first columns

Tags: bash, awk, sed, grep, text-processing

I have a huge CSV file with pairs of unique combinations. I need to extract N random lines of this file, but I need that the strings in col 1&2 to be unique, so that the list of unique strings in col 1&2 strings combined is equal to 2*N.

For example given, this input file:

```
A,B,0.1747
B,C,0.373
C,D,0.585
E,J,0.8585
E,A,0.5657
F,A,0.5656
```

Possible desired output for 3 random lines would be:

```
A,B,0.1747
C,D,0.585
E,J,0.8585
```

or

```
B,C,0.373
E,J,0.8585
F,A,0.5656
```

So far I have tried to reduce the file to unique strings in both col 1 and 2 separately using:

```
shuf file.csv | awk  -F',' '!a[$1]++' | awk  -F',' '!a[$2]++'
```

to get

```
B,C,0.373
E,A,0.5657
A,B,0.1747
C,D,0.585
```

I don't think this is the correct approach. Is there a way of looping through rows and not consider the row if a string is already present in either of two columns?

Comment: And what did you try? How did it fail?

Comment: So far I've tried to shuffle the entire file using ```shuf``` and then filtering successively the first and second column for duplicates using ```awk  -F',' '!a[$1]++'``` but I don't think it is the correct approach

Comment: Please review [ask]. Especially you seem to have missed the concept of actually asking a question based on what you have tried, while providing details like an [mre]. Please [edit] accordingly and to add useful info, instead of putting them into comments.

Comment: In addition to that I would need more explanation, maybe more examples, on what you are trying to do.

Comment: So basically you are looking for an algorithm. How about this: First you use `shuf` to create a random permutation of the file. Then you read through the file sequentially, storing the lines into an associative array, where the key is the first two fields of the line, and the value the whole line. Once your array grows to the size of 200 entries, you are done.

Comment: I don't understand why this question has been closed as "not focused enough". IMHO it is perfectly focused on one single goal. It could maybe be improved (for instance by stating what to do with lines with same first and second fields), but it is focused.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use `awk` twice there is usually a better solution with only one `awk` script. You can try:

```
shuf file.csv |
  awk -F, '!(a[$1]+a[$2]) {a[$1]++; a[$2]++; n++; print} n==200 {exit}'
```

Variant using `in` and `next`:

```
shuf file.csv |
  awk -F, '$1 in a || $2 in a {next} {a[$1]; a[$2]; n++; print} n==200 {exit}'
```

Note: your example has no input lines with identical first and second fields. But if this can happen and you want to skip these lines you can use:

```
shuf file.csv |
  awk -F, '($1!=$2) && !(a[$1]+a[$2]) {a[$1]++; a[$2]++; n++; print}
           n==200 {exit}'
```

Or:

```
shuf file.csv |
  awk -F, '$1==$2 || $1 in a || $2 in a {next} {a[$1]; a[$2]; n++; print}
           n==200 {exit}'
```

Comment: Merci beaucoup!